# In this case i want to undestand, why is the output 10 instead of 20?

Tags: c

i want to understand why output in  this code is 10 not 20

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int check (int, int);

int main()
{
    int c;
    c = check(10, 20);
    printf("c=%d\n", c);
    return 0;
}
int check(int i, int j)
{
    int *p, *q;
    p=&i;
    q=&j;
    i>=45?*p:*q;
}
```

Comment: `check` doesn't return anything... This shouldn't even compile.

Comment: You're causing undefined behavior, the output can be anything.

Comment: If you change the last line to `return i>=45?*p:*q;` you'll get the expected output.

Comment: You should enable warnings in your compiler. For GCC you can do this with open `-Wall`. This should give you some message about "reaching end of non-void function without returning a value". And of course, read your warnings and handle them.

Comment: always fell that the default should be -wall -werror to help out new coders.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the return value of the check() function is undefined behavior.

In order to get the expected output of `20` you would have to use the return statement like this `return i>=45?*p:*q;`
You need to do this to actually tell the compiler to write the result to the return register.

If you don't do this the function simply exits without explicitly writing the result value to the return register. Instead the register content is simply left in the state it was last in (in your case 10), but this is in no way guaranteed and will very likely vary with the compiler used.

---

If you really want to understand it on an instruction level have a look here: [godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:___c,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:19,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:19,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:19,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:19),source:'%23include%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%0Aint+check+(int,+int)%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++int+c%3B%0A++++c+%3D+check(10,+20)%3B%0A++++printf(%22c%3D%25d%5Cn%22,+c)%3B%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%0Aint+check(int+i,+int+j)%0A%7B%0A++++int+*p,+*q%3B%0A++++p%3D%26i%3B%0A++++q%3D%26j%3B%0A++++i%3E%3D45%3F*p:*q%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cg101,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:'',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+10.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)
There on the right you can see the x86 assembly of your program, and if you look closely you can see that the compiler just so happens to use the `eax` register to compare the value which is also by ABI convention the register used for function return values.